# Magento 2 : Change Language Code

Tags: magento2.2.6, stores, locale

I'm facing issues while update language code for website.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
```

I want to change it with **en-GB**. I've already locale setup with default configurations.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

> Set Locale from Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> General >> General >> Locale Option >> Locale >> English (United Kingdom)

Set above configuration and run below command, It will generate only `pub\static\frontend\VendorName\thmemeName\en_GB`

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Already did this. I mention this is question. If you've other solution Please go ahead.

Comment: Have you tried with the localization tag?
"php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB"

Comment: Did you check it this folder create or not? pub\static\frontend\VendorName\thmemeName\en_GB

Comment: If not then you can try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB command as per Milind Singh mention here. Because, by default it will deploy en_US

Answer (score 0):

[image: First click on this Account setting link]

[image: and then from here you can change you lanuge]

Follow these steps to change the lanugage.